# Issue setting environment variable that points to smb

Tags: mojave, smb, oracle

Can someone tell me the proper syntax for setting an environment variable that points to a smb volume directory?

What I have tried so far:

```
TNS_ADMIN=/Volumes/abc
TNS_ADMIN=smb://servername/abc
TNS_ADMIN=/servername/abc
```

Additional info, I have Oracle InstantClient installed and I'm trying to use SQLPlus. Except, the connection file I need is located in the shared directory located in the aforementioned smb volume.  I'm trying to set the environment variable (TNS_ADMIN) such that it points Oracle to look at the smb volume, where the file is located.  Nothing appears to work.  Looking for guidance on what the proper syntax should be on setting an environment variable that points to a smb volume.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking and whether you are actually asking one question or several questions at once? What do you need the path for the shared drive for, how do you use it afterwards (best shown with examples)?

Comment: Also, `PATH` has a special meaning in shells and is used as a list of directories to look for executables. You need to use another name for your own variables.

Comment: Have you mounted the SMB directory, meaning can you access tns_names.ora (the connection file) in Finder?

Comment: @nohillside - Yes, I have.  From the mounted volume Get Info, the server name appears as smb://servername/abc.  I'm hoping that by knowing what the correct syntax should be - it will help me determine if it's an issue with what I defined in the env variable or Oracle related.

Comment: Open Finder and drag&drop tns_names.ora into an open Terminal window with a shell prompt. The path shown is the value you need.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Terminal
- Open Finder and navigate to the folder containing the connection file
- Drag&drop `tns_names.ora` into the Terminal window

The path shown is the value you need.